# How can I programmatically retrieve all alternative gene names from Wormbase?

Tags: wormbase

I'm trying to get all C. elegans genes from Wormbase programmatically, as well as all of their alternative gene names. To do this, I'm using [intermine](http://intermine.org/).

I was able to obtain all genes, but not ALL alternative names. The code below retrieves the genes' primary identifiers, and their "secondary identifiers."

```
from intermine.webservice import Service
service = Service("http://intermine.wormbase.org/tools/wormmine/service")

query=service.new_query("Gene")
# 6239 is the taxonId for C. elegans
query.add_constraint("organism.taxonId","=","6239")
query.select("*")

all_wormbase_genes_symbol = list()
all_wormbase_genes_sID = list()

for row in query.rows(start=0):
    # get primary symbol/ID
    all_wormbase_genes_symbol.append(row["symbol"])
    # get secondary ID
    all_wormbase_genes_sID.append(row["secondaryIdentifier"])
```

I tried to look for other keys in `row` that might contain this information by first retrieving the list of all possible keys:

```
k = set()
for row in query.rows(start=0):
    k.update(row.keys())
```

but none have what I want:

```
{'Gene.automatedDescription',
 'Gene.biotype',
 'Gene.briefDescription',
 'Gene.description',
 'Gene.geneticPosition',
 'Gene.id',
 'Gene.lastUpdated',
 'Gene.length',
 'Gene.name',
 'Gene.operon',
 'Gene.primaryIdentifier',
 'Gene.score',
 'Gene.scoreType',
 'Gene.secondaryIdentifier',
 'Gene.symbol'}
```

Comment: I don't know via `intermine`, but you can download a file with this information from the FTP at `/pub/wormbase/releases/WS287/species/c_elegans/PRJNA13758/annotation/c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS287.geneOtherIDs.txt.gz` (changing to the appropriate WSxxx version)